# How do I display a file or directory browser dialog using MATLAB

Tags: user-interface, matlab

I have created a blank GUI and now I want to program a push button to display a file or directory browser dialog.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question could use a little more detail, but here's a general suggestion to get you started...

You could set the callback for your push button so that it invokes one of the [built-in dialog boxes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/predefined-dialog-boxes.html) available in MATLAB. You may be most interested in [`UIGETDIR`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uigetdir.html) or [`UIGETFILE`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uigetfile.html) to browse for and select a directory or file, respectively.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to gnovice's advice, if you want your directory browser to be embedded within your GUI (as opposed to opening in a separate dialog window), you can use Java component. Take a look at my [UICOMPONENT utility](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14583-uicomponent-expands-uicontrol-to-all-java-classes) on the File Exchange for a working example.

Alternately, you can design your own tree-view of folder contents within a matlab panel, using the documented yet unsupported UITREE function or a Java JTree component (take a look at my [UIINSPECT](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/17935-uiinspect-display-methodspropertiescallbacks-of-an-object) or [FINDJOBJ](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14317-findjobj-find-java-handles-of-matlab-graphic-objects) utilities for working examples).